# Spring data mongodb, how to set SSL?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have so far failed to find a good explanation/doc on the topic.

I am using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and my code looks like this:

```
   @Bean
   public MongoClientFactoryBean mongo() {
      MongoClientFactoryBean mongo = new MongoClientFactoryBean();
      mongo.setHost(host);
      mongo.setPort(port);
      mongo.setCredentials(new MongoCredential[]{MongoCredential.createCredential(username, database, password.toCharArray())});
      return mongo;
   }

   @Bean
   public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(Mongo mongo) throws Exception {
      return new MongoTemplate(mongo, database);
   }
```

Do you know how I should configure SSL for this?  And can I allow invalid certificate?

The equivalent mongo command line would be

```
mongo --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates --host <host> --port <port>
```

Comment: I see that all the answers state "javax.net.ssl.keyStore" this is infact incorrect as it is the truststore that changes not the keystore, so either you should use 

        System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","<path>");
        System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","<password>");

Or add the cacert to the java trustsrore using (Java 9 and above):
keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -cacerts -file ca-certificate.crt -alias your-alias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is explained in the docs : please refer below :

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/reference/connecting/ssl/?_ga=1.122423051.1001600813.1475930911

Also following configuration can be used to enable it

```
    @Bean
    public  MongoClientOptions mongoClientOptions(){
        System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","<<PATH TO KEYSTOR >>");
        System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","PASSWORD");   
        MongoClientOptions.Builder builder = MongoClientOptions.builder();
        MongoClientOptions options=builder.sslEnabled(true).build();        
        return options;
    }
```

pass the mongo client options to MongoClient instance as an argument

```
public MongoClient(ServerAddress addr, MongoClientOptions options) {
        super(addr, options);
    }
```

Adding further, when mongo processs is started with

mongo 
    --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates --host  --port

clients connecting to the mongo process dont have to set any options to support this.

Comment: I think that your comment is valid for the library "mongo-java-driver", not for the "spring-data-mongodb" one. This reply seems to fit better to the question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60168414/7658979

Comment: @Alessandro Point taken. Will try to update based on your comments thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to connect your spring boot app with mongodb, you can use the keyStore and trustStore with java code. So you dont have to add your certificate via command line. If you are using cloud foundry you can connect your app with mongodbServices and then you have all the credentials you need in System.getEnv("VCAP_SERVICES").

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MongoConfiguration.class);
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    private String defaultDatabase; //database you want to connect
    private String host;
    private int port;
    private String authenticationDb; //usually admin
    private String username;
    private char[] password;
    private String certificateDecoded; //your CA Certifcate decoded (starts with BEGIN CERTIFICATE)

    public MongoConfiguration() {
        //method for credentials initialization
    }

    //you can't set replicaset=replset in mongooptions so if you want set replicaset, you have to use 
    // customEditorConfigurer in combintaion with class that implementsPropertyEditorRegistrar
    @Bean
    public static CustomEditorConfigurer customEditorConfigurer(){
        CustomEditorConfigurer configurer = new CustomEditorConfigurer();
        configurer.setPropertyEditorRegistrars(
                new PropertyEditorRegistrar[]{new ServerAddressPropertyEditorRegistrar()});
        return configurer;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return authenticationDb;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress(host, port)), mongoCredentials(), mongoClientOptions());
        return mongoClient;
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoClientOptions mongoClientOptions() {
        MongoClientOptions.Builder mongoClientOptions = MongoClientOptions.builder().sslInvalidHostNameAllowed(true).sslEnabled(true);
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(certificateDecoded.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            X509Certificate caCert = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(inputStream);

            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory
                    .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            keyStore.load(null); // You don't need the KeyStore instance to come from a file.
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("caCert", caCert);

            trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);

            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
            mongoClientOptions.sslContext(sslContext);
            mongoClientOptions.sslInvalidHostNameAllowed(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }

        return mongoClientOptions.build();
    }

    private MongoCredential mongoCredentials() {
        return MongoCredential.createCredential(username, authenticationDb, password);
    }

//With MongoTemplate you have access to db.
    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
        SimpleMongoDbFactory factory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient(), defaultDatabase);
        return new MongoClient(factory);

    }
}


public final class ServerAddressPropertyEditorRegistrar implements PropertyEditorRegistrar {
    @Override
    public void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry registry) {
        registry.registerCustomEditor(ServerAddress[].class, new ServerAddressPropertyEditor());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Spring Boot 2.3.4 and Reactive Mongo in Eclipse:

pfx goes into src/test/resources

```
  @Bean @Profile("dev")
  public MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettingsDev() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","target/test-classes/xxx.pfx");
    System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","xxx");  
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getDefault();
    MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                                                      .applyToSslSettings(builder -> {
                                                        builder.enabled(true);
                                                        builder.context(sslContext);
                                                      })
                                                      .build();
    return settings;
  }
```

bootstrap.yml for connection with x.509:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      database: database_name
      uri: mongodb://CN=xxx.xxx.com@cloud.xxx.com:62017/?authMechanism=MONGODB-X509&tls=true&authSource=$external
```

Update for Spring Boot 2.4.5

```
  @Bean @Profile("dev")
  public MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettingsDev(
    MongoProperties properties,
    Environment environment
  ) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","target/test-classes/xxx.pfx");
    System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","xxx");  
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getDefault();
    MongoClientSettings.Builder builder = MongoClientSettings.builder();
    builder.applyToSslSettings(b -> {
      b.enabled(true);
      b.context(sslContext);
    });
    new MongoPropertiesClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer(properties, environment).customize(builder);
    return builder.build();
  }
```

Another way of setting the SSLContext:

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("xxx.pfx");
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
ks.load(resource.getInputStream(), "xxx".toCharArray());
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadKeyMaterial(ks, "xxx".toCharArray()).build();
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much. However, I had to change `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` and  `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword` to following properties - `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` and `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword`

Comment: Thank you for posting the Update for Spring Boot 2.4.5!

Comment: the truststore is for use with other 3rd party external sites you want to trust (such as google.com, etc.), whereas the keystore is a secure place for your custom certs.

Answer (score 1):

You can also build the ssl enabled mongo instance in the following way.

```
public @Bean MongoClient mongoClient() throws Exception {
    return new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://username:password@host:port/db?ssl=true"));
}
```

If you using spring boot then it can be configurable in application.properties or application.yml in the following way

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://username:password@host:port/db?ssl=true
```

Comment: The use of the Java Keystore can be for SSL/TLS, or it could be used for x.509 authentication.  When used with authentication, simply creating the connection string is not sufficient.  You need to also add the x.509 credential - which is a user name which refers to a specific cert in the java keystore for the purpose of using the cert in place of a password.  SSL/TLS is easy.  x.509 authentication is not.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Bean as below and use where ever needed.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "XXXXX")
@EnableMongoRepositories({ "XXXXXX" })
public class ApplicationConfig {
System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "<CERT>.keystore");
System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","<password>"); 

MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createMongoX509Credential(
            "C=US,ST=XXXXXXX,O=XXXXXX... "
            );
MongoClientSettings.Builder settings = MongoClientSettings.builder();
settings.credential(credential);
    
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getDefault();
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
.applyToSslSettings(builder -> {
                builder.enabled(true);
                builder.context(sslContext);}).credential(credential).applyConnectionString(new     ConnectionString("mongodb://<host>:<port>/?authMechanism=MONGODB-X509&ssl=true"))
                                                      .build();
com.mongodb.client.MongoClient client = MongoClients.create(settings);
SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory factory = new     SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory(client, <database>);
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(factory);
return mongoTemplate;
    }
}
```